# Represent an array of objects as a protobuf message

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

I would like to create a protobuf message which represents an array of objects.

**Example**

```
[
  {
    "firstKey": "firstValue",
    "secondKey": "secondValue",
  },
  {
    "firstKey": "firstValue",
    "secondKey": "secondValue",
  },
  ...
]
```

**Pseudo code** (not a valid syntax)

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Entry {
  string firstKey = 1;
  string secondKey = 2;
}

repeated message Response {
  ...Entry;
}
```

I cannot find a way to do this. Is it even possible or am I forced to nest it like this?

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Entry {
  string firstKey = 1;
  string secondKey = 2;
}

message Response {
  repeated Entry data = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SingleObject {
  string name = 1;
  int32 age = 2;
}

message ObjectArray {
  repeated SingleObject objects = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this directly with Protocol Buffers because ProtoBuf is a binary serialization format, and its messages are structured differently from JSON arrays. ProtoBuf messages don't inherently have a root array like JSON.

Instead you can achieve this in your application code by constructing a JSON array and serializing/wrapping it with an object matching the ProtoBuf Message.